# Nested async lambda not awaited

Tags: c#, mongodb, lambda, async-await

The following code does not return the entire collection it is iterating. The returned array has an arbitrary length on every run. What's wrong?

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetClients()
{
    var clientInfoCollection = new ConcurrentBag<ClientInfoModel>();

    await _client.Iterate(async (client) =>
    {
        clientInfoCollection.Add(new ClientInfoModel
        {
            name = client.name,
            userCount = await _user.Count(clientId)
        });
    });

    return Ok(clientInfoCollection.ToArray());
}
```

The following code uses the new async MongoDB C# driver

```
public async Task Iterate(Action<TDocument> processor)
{
    await _collection.Find<TDocument>(_ => true).ForEachAsync(processor);
}
```

Comment: How is `Iterate` defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you're seeing arbitrary number of values is in the fact the `Iterate` receives a delegate of type `Action<T>`, which is equivalent to `async void`, effectively making this a "fire-and-forget" style of execution.

The inner method isn't actually aware that an async delegate has been passed to it, hence it iterates the collection without actually asynchronously waiting for each item to complete.

What you need to do instead is make the method parameter a delegate of type `Func<TDocument, Task>` [and use the proper overload of `ForEachAsync`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IAsyncCursorExtensions_ForEachAsync__1_2.htm):

```
public Task Iterate(Func<TDocument, Task> processor)
{
    return _collection.Find<TDocument>(_ => true).ForEachAsync(processor);
}
```

You can see the [source here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/aa632410c2db832ad802ff57d6acac64c838ddfa/src/MongoDB.Driver.Core/IAsyncCursor.cs):

```
public static async Task ForEachAsync<TDocument>(
                    this IAsyncCursor<TDocument> source, 
                    Func<TDocument, int, Task> processor,
                    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    Ensure.IsNotNull(source, "source");
    Ensure.IsNotNull(processor, "processor");

    // yes, we are taking ownership... assumption being that they've
    // exhausted the thing and don't need it anymore.
    using (source)
    {
        var index = 0;
        while (await source.MoveNextAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            foreach (var document in source.Current)
            {
                await processor(document, index++).ConfigureAwait(false);
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You create the threads, and set them off. From there you can't know what happens. But your codes next step is to return, so you are gambling that the threads will execute faster, than your main thread.

In normal threading scenarios, you will join the threads, who are adding items to the bag. Where a join, is the threads, waiting for the other threads to execute and thereby still being async, but waiting to return before everything is completed.

Which is perfectly explained here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/thread-join